# Fpdf to google docs

Tags: html, pdf, fpdf

How to view pdf created by FPDF to google docs?

I want to display the PDF file directly in my webpage so that the user can review the PDF file before downloaind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the full URL of your creation script to the viewer:

E.g.: https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffpdf.org%2Fen%2Ftutorial%2Ftuto6.php&embedded=true